# Awaiting the completion of a server request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I faced the following problem.

I have a Server object `server` which exposes `TriggerStateChangeAsync()` which return an `Task<bool>` this task finished with `true` as soon the request for the state changed is send off to the server and with `false` if the request could not be send to the server. The object also exposses the event `StateChanged` which will be raised if the server reports that the state has changed.

What I now wanted to do is to write a wrapper Methode which will finishes (async) if after the state has changed or the request could not be send to the server.

It looks like:

```cs
public static async Task<boo> TriggerStateChangeAndWaitAsync(this Server server, int stateId) 
{
    var stateChanged = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // local methode
    void handler(object sender, StateEventArgs e)
    {
        // this handels that the state has now actually changed
        if (e.StateId = id)
        {
            server.StateChanged -= handler;
            stateChanged.SetResult(true);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        server.StateChanged += handler;

        // this task finishes when the request is send off to the server
        bool sendToServer = await server.TriggerStateChangeAsync(id);

        if (sendToServer)
        {
            await stateChanged.Task.WithTimeout(1000);
        }

        return sendToServer;
    }
    finally
    {
        server.StateChanged -= handler;
    }
}
```

Is this an good approch for that? And is it okay to leave the `TaskCompletionSource` uncompleted in the case that the request could not be sent?

---

The method `WithTimeout(1000)` is just an extension methode for `Task`that is just

```cs
public static async Task<R> WithTimeout<R>(this Task<R> task, int timeout)
{
    using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
        if (completedTask == task)
        {
            timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            return await task;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? Can I somehow improve the question?